# Best practice to store variables for much form fields of the same type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form that looks like this:

[image: Form picture]



    For each row of achievements I have two properties in my viewmodel and 2 inputs in my html:

```
                <table id="submissionTable">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Place</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><b>Event</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tablerow0">
                    <td width="135"><input type="number" min="1" asp-for="AchievementsRank1" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td width="20"><span></span></td>
                    <td width="590"><select asp-for="event1" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Events>()" class="form-control"></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tablerow1">
                    <td width="135"><input type="number" min="1" asp-for="AchievementsRank2" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td width="20"><span></span></td>
                    <td width="590"><select asp-for="event2" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Events>()" class="form-control"></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tablerow2">
                    <td width="135"><input type="number" min="1" asp-for="AchievementsRank3" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td width="20"><span></span></td>
                    <td width="590"><select asp-for="event3" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Events>()" class="form-control"></select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    [Display(Name = "Achievements")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Atleast one achievement is required.")]
    public int AchievementsRank1 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Atleast one achievement is required.")]
    public Events event1 { get; set; }

    public int? AchievementsRank2 { get; set; }
    public Events event2 { get; set; }

    public int? AchievementsRank3 { get; set; }
    public Events event3 { get; set; }
```

But what if let's say I'd want 10 or more rows of achievements? I would have to add all those properties and inputs for each row... There must be an easier way to do this I just don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create a class that represent you 2 datas association (rank / event). Then in your viewmodel you can create a List of this items, initialized with 3 empty instance. Then with some javascript you could try to add (and remove) rows to your html with a plus and minus icon with some Html.IdFor(m => m...). You'll prefer to use a for instead of a foreach.

I hope I have been clear enough about this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify your model to something like this:

```
public class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
        Achievements = new List<Achievement>
        {

            // initialize 3 achievements
            new Achievement(),
            new Achievement(),
            new Achievement()
        };
    }


    public string Username { get; set; }

    public List<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
}

public class Achievement
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

and your view should be like this:

```
<input asp-for="Username" type="text" />

@foreach (var achievement in Model.Achievements)
{
    int index = Model.Achievements.IndexOf(achievement);

    <input asp-for="achievements[index].Rank" type="text" />
    <select asp-for="achievements[index].EventId" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Events>()" class="form-control">
        <option></option>
    </select>
}
```